# How to change the df column name within a list

Tags: r, list, tidyverse

I have a list of dfs. The dfs all have the same column names. I would like to:

(1) Change one of the column names to the name of the df within the list

(2) `full_join` all the dfs after name change

#### Example of my list:

```
my_list <- list(one = data.frame(Type  = c(1,2,3), Class = c("a", "a", "b")),
                two = data.frame(Type  = c(1,2,3), Class = c("a", "a", "b")))
```

#### Output that I want:

```
data.frame(Type = c(1,2,3),
           one  = c("a", "a", "b"),
           two  = c("a", "a", "b"))

  Type one two
    1   a   a
    2   a   a
    3   b   b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could possible use `dplyr::bind_rows` combined with `tidyr::spread` to achieve the same result (if you are happy to consider alternative approaches). For example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
my_list %>% bind_rows(.id = "groups") %>% spread(groups, Class)

#>   Type one two
#> 1    1   a   a
#> 2    2   a   a
#> 3    3   b   b
```

Comment: This is fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

The first step can be tricky, but it's simple if you iterate over `names(my_list)`.

```
transformed <- sapply(names(my_list), function(name) {
  df <- my_list[[name]]
  colnames(df)[colnames(df) == 'Class'] <- name
  df
}, simplify = FALSE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)
```

With `purrr::reduce` and `dplyr::full_join` the result can be obtained:

```
purrr::reduce(transformed, dplyr::full_join)
#   Type one two
# 1    1   a   a
# 2    2   a   a
# 3    3   b   b
```